# Function resample Matlab

Tags: matlab

What is the operation that makes Matlab resample command to get the new sampling numbers?
For example, if I have the vector

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
xx = resample (x, 1, 4)

xx = 0.8403    5.3900    7.4677
```

How do you get the numbers inside the vector xx?
I understand from the page on the matlab site that the resample method changes the sampling frequency of the signal in 1/4. 
I did not understand, however, how do to obtain numbers of the new vector.
Can anyone help me in this calculation?

Comment: Do you mean you want to read to the source code of the `resample` function?

Comment: I want to understand why I obtain 0.8403 as the first number of xx, why 5.3900 as second number, why 7.4677 as the third number. Is that an interpolation?

Comment: Yes that's approximately what resampling is when you reduce the sample rate. You should read [Decimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimation_(signal_processing)).

Comment: I read also that page but I don't understand what is the operation for obtain 0.8403 for example.

Comment: It's not that easy. Prior to decimation, an anti-aliasing filter is applied (essentially, a 1/4 lowpass). The exact values depend on which particular lowpass filter is used. My Matlab says "using a polyphase anti-aliasing filter" and "digital anti-alias filter is designed via windowing". It calls `firls` to design the filter, using a Kaiser window.

Comment: Thank you very very much. You understood my doubt perfectly!!!!!